# If I drop all explicit references to an observable I've subscribed to, will it be garbage collected?

Tags: garbage-collection, rx-java

I have an observable that emits a response from a remote server.  I subscribe to it with an action that will stuff the result in a cache.

- Once all of my own explicit references to the original observable are gone, is there danger that the side-effecting action mentioned above will fail to act?
- More generally, what do I need to know as an rxjava user about garbage collection and rxjava?

Bonus: Here's a clojure experiment demonstrating an observable being held onto while there's a subscriber, or maybe it's just showing a side-effect of ever subscribing to an observable.

```clj
(ns adhoc.rx-gc
  "Testing behavior of RxJava and garbage collection."
  (:require [rx.lang.clojure.core :as rx])
  (:import (java.lang.ref WeakReference)
           (java.util.concurrent TimeUnit)
           (rx Observable)))

(defn test-gc
  [sub?]
  ;; Hold source in an atom to be sure we can wipe references to it
  ;; and not worry about lexical scope.
  (let [a-src (atom (.delay (rx/return "hello") 5 TimeUnit/SECONDS))
        w-src (WeakReference. @a-src)]
    (when sub?
      (rx/subscribe @a-src
                    #(do (println "Value:" %)
                         (println "On-update ref:" (.get w-src)))))
    (reset! a-src nil)
    (System/gc)
    (println "After-gc ref:" (.get w-src))))

(comment
  (test-gc false)
  ;; After-gc ref: nil

  (test-gc true)
  ;; After-gc ref: #<Observable rx.Observable@21863f3b>
  ;; Value: hello
  ;; On-update ref: #<Observable rx.Observable@21863f3b>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Once all of my own explicit references to the original observable are gone, is there danger that the side-effecting action mentioned above will fail to act?

It depends. If you use `Scheduler`, there may be some implicit references to your `Observable` in some thread of `Scheduler`.

> More generally, what do I need to know as an rxjava user about garbage collection and rxjava?

Make sure you call `Subsscription.unsubscribe` when you want to release resources and never ignore `Subscription`s returned by `Observable.subscribe`.